# Combination of items with and without replacement

Tags: combinatorics

How do you determine the number of combinations of items if some items can be replaced and some cannot?  For example, I have $2$ lists:

$X = \{A,B,C\}$ - cannot be replaced

$Y = \{1,2,3\}$ - can be replaced

How many combinations are there when combining both lists?  I know that all of the combinations with replacement is $\dfrac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$ and without replacement is $\dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.

How do I combine the two?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So you want say $13$ items from these? Or are the numbers of items from $X$ and from $Y$ individually specified?

Comment: @André Nicolas The total number of items is specified, like 13, as in the latter part of your answer below.

Comment: Then as described we get a sum of products of two binomial coefficients. I believe that in general this sum does not simplify in any nice way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want $r$ of the no replacement type, and $s$ of the replacement type, where $r$ and $s$ are **given**, then just count separately the number of ways to obtain $r$ no replacement objects, and the number of ways to obtain $s$ replacement objects, using the formulas you quoted. Then multiply.

If only the *total* number of items to be picked is specified, like $13$,  then calculate separately the probabilities of $0$ of the no replacement type, $13$ of the replacement type, $1$ of no replacment, $12$ of replacement, and so on, using the method of the first paragraph, and add up.